# Dropzone.js unable to map to viewmodel

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have the following drop zone js and have a file input hidden with an asp-for tag which should map to my viewmodel. However there is nothing being mapped. The controller accepts a parameter List FormFiles.

```
  <form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Customer" class="js-step-form js-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                              data-hs-step-form-options='{
                                          "progressSelector": "#validationFormProgress",
                                          "stepsSelector": "#validationFormContent",
                                          "endSelector": "#validationFormFinishBtn",
                                          "isValidate": true
                                        }'>
                            <!-- Step -->
                            <!-- End Step -->
                            <!-- Content Step Form -->
                            <div id="validationFormContent">

                                <div id="validationFormAccount" class="active">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <!-- Form Group -->
                                            <div class="form-group js-form-message mb-3">
                                                <label class="input-label">Loyality Spend</label>
                                                <input id="LoyalitySpendTextBox" type="text" class="form-control stringValidation" required
                                                       data-msg="Please enter Loyality Spend." placeholder="Loyality Spend" aria-label="Current Value" value="@Model.Customer.LoyaltySpend" asp-for="@Model.Customer.LoyaltySpend">


                                            </div>
                                            <!-- End Form Group -->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <!-- Form Group -->
                                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                                <label class="input-label">Documents</label>
                                                <!-- Dropzone -->
                                                <div id="attachFilesLabel" class="js-dropzone dropzone-custom custom-file-boxed">
                                                    <div class="dz-message dz-filename">
                                                        <img class="avatar avatar-xl avatar-4by3 mb-3" src="~/front-dashboard-v1.1/src/assets/svg/illustrations/browse.svg" alt="Image Description">
                                                        <h5>Drag and drop your file here</h5>
                                                        <p class="mb-2">or</p>
                                                        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-white" id="chose_files_btn" onclick="doOpen(event)">
                                                            Browse File
                                                            <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.FormFiles" id="File" name="File" size="1" style="display: none"  />
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- End Dropzone -->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- End Form Group -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind data with name FormFiles,you can use `paramName` of Dropzone.And if you want to upload files when button click,try to use `autoProcessQueue: false,`,and in button click event add  `e.preventDefault();wrapperThis.processQueue();`.If you want to delete files,you need to add `addRemoveLinks: true,` and use `removedfile`. Here is a demo.

View:

```
<form  asp-action="Upload" asp-antiforgery="false"
  class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="fallback">
    <input asp-for="FormFiles" type="file" multiple />
    
</div>
```

js:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.2/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.2/dropzone.css"/>
    <script>
function myParamName() {
            return "FormFiles";
        }
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        paramName: myParamName, // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        addRemoveLinks: true, 
        removedfile: function (file) {
            file.previewElement.remove();
        },
        init: function () {
            console.log("active");
            var wrapperThis = this;

            $("#submit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                wrapperThis.processQueue();
            });
        },
        accept: function (file, done) {
            done();
        }
    };
    </script>
```

action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Upload(List<IFormFile> FormFiles)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: What progress bar?With Dropzone?

Comment: Yes with drop zone

Comment: I updated my answer with a new gif,do you mean the progress bar in it?If so,it is available by default in Dropzone.

Comment: How do I submit files on button click

Comment: $(document).on('ready', function () {
            // INITIALIZATION OF DROPZONE FILE ATTACH MODULE
            // =======================================================
            $('.js-dropzone').each(function () {
                var dropzone = $.HSCore.components.HSDropzone.init('#' + $(this).attr('id'));

            });
        });

Comment: Refer to the latest answer.When button click,files will be uploaded.

Comment: Please can you show me how to display images on edit form

Comment: When I want to delete old image and add new one.

Comment: Refer to my latest answer.

Comment: You can try yo create a new question,I think it is a new question about binding multiple properties to a model.